# Cannot open subfolder when browsing for documents in gedit ( and in Sublime text editor and Visual Studio code IDE)

Tags: nautilus, gedit

In the gedit ( and in Sublime and the visual studio code IDE ) when I go to browse my folders to find a file using Open>Other Documents, clicking on a subfolder in the central panel to open that up doesn't do anything.  I attach a pic to explain. It used to work fine for years and years but recently clicking the mouse buttons seemingly wouldn't register the clicks and I messed around with accessibility options and click delay timings, and single click/ double click options in Settings before deciding it was the mouse. I replaced the mouse but the problem persists.

STUFF THAT WORKS FINE:
The Standard Files (i'm guessing that's nautilus since it looks a lot like it ) files explorer works fine in letting me open up subfolders when exploring files. Nautilus on its own from the  command line works fine
Spyder ( a python IDE) works fine. 
LibraOffice 6.0.7.3 did not work. But I upgraded to 6.4.2.2 and the Writer and Calc now work fine.
The common theme I think is that all these apps that work don't use the default standard subapp for exploring the file system, but use their own - one can tell since the look and feel is quite different from the nautilus look and feel.

I created a new account called testedit. gedit lets me open up subfolders just fine.

I logged in remotely into my machine from ANOTHER machine with the broken id using ssh -X ... gedit works fine there. But when I do ssh -X localhost gedit does not work.

I'd appreciate help here.

My configuration is:
Ubuntu 18.04.4
64Gb memory AMD Ryzen 7 2700x
graphics GeForce GT710
Gnome 3.28.2

Attached pic:
[gedit window for folder exploration with Other Documents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ECRgc.png)

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, you can go up/down directory by `Alt+Up/Down` or directly open file `Ctl+L` without mouse operations. If they work, the problem comes from mouse action, confirm your mouse buttons by `xev` in Terminal and reassign them by using `xinput` or `xbindkey` and etc.

Comment: I tried Alt+UP and indeed it t traverses the directory upwards. And for example, if i go UP the tree twice, Alt + Down will traverse down, but only twice. I can't down any further.

Comment: Ctl+L indeed opens up a search box where I can enter the name of the  folder I want to open and it will open it, so yup I have a workaround I guess. Also I started up xev pressed left mouse button and it records it as :    buttonPress event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x3800002,
    root 0x43b, subw 0x0, time 737351, (67,101), root:(2142,246),
    state 0x0, button 1, same_screen YES

ButtonRelease .....

Comment: So from the xev output, it seems that the left button click  event is being seen by  Xserver but it seems not to get passed back to the folder exploration subapp, which I guess is nautilus, in subapp mode, inside gedit, sublime, and visualstudio code. But the folder exploration in spyder, in latest version of Office Calc works fine. I'd appreciate more ideas on how to go about further debugging this.

Comment: gedit, sublime and VScode are all written in python, In these several years, version 3 is taking over version 2. And Sublime and VScode are old ones. I don't get gedit trapped in the same way... So anyway, try to reinstall nautilus or remove its configuration files under your $HOME and reboot. That will do, if not, reinstall all of them use `--purge` or use alternative software likewise Pluma.